# How do I invoke a non-interactive lisp function interactively?

Tags: functions

This is dim, but I've forgotten how to do this, and I can't work it out, sorry:

I'm in python mode with elpy, and I want to run the function
`python-nav-beginning-of-defun`
in a python buffer, to see what it does

```
M-x python-nav-beginning-of-defun
```

won't work, because the function is not a command (it has no `interactive` spec).

And putting `(python-nav-beginning-of-defun)` in a buffer and using `C-x C-e` will disturb the buffer and move the point.

I seem to remember that there's some way that I can type `(python-nav-beginning-of-defun)` in a mini-buffer somewhere, and see what it does to the python buffer, without disturbing the buffer.

Can anyone tell me what it's called / what the magic keys are?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for <kbd>M-:</kbd> which runs the command `eval-expression`

Answer (score 2):

You can execute Lisp code with the command [`eval-expression`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Eval.html#index-eval_002dexpression-2955), bound to `M-:` by default (i.e. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd>).

At the prompt, type the code to evaluate. To call a function, put the function name in parentheses.

```
M-: (python-nav-beginning-of-defun) RET
```

If there are arguments, put them after the function name, within the parentheses.

```
M-: (+ 2 2) RET
```

The return value of the function is displayed in the echo area. (In your case it isn't interesting, I mention that for the general case.) If it doesn't fit, or you want to see it afterwards or to copy-paste it, switch to the `*Messages*` buffer. If you'd rather assign the result to a variable, use the `setq` function:

```
M-: (setq x (+ 2 2)) RET
```

If the code triggers an error and a debugger window pops up, press `q` in the debugger window. If the code prompts for something and you want to cancel, press `ESC` three times (`keyboard-escape-quit`). If the code goes into a tight loop, break with `C-g` as usual.